# js function that created a specific object taking values from SerializeArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have this this array that I take from `serializeArray()` function and I want to pass that key/values to an specific js object.

I have **this result** from `$("selector :pseudoSelector").serializeArray()`

and gives me this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Address",
    "value": "Calle pizzarro 56"
  },
  {
    "name": "1",
    "value": "83"
  },
  {
    "name": "3",
    "value": "340"
  },
  {
    "name": "5",
    "value": "340"
  },
  {
    "name": "7",
    "value": "hi how are you?"
  },
  {
    "name": "latitud",
    "value": "87798"
  },
  {
    "name": "longitude",
    "value": "-8,208914"
  }
]
```

Then I want to transform that data in an object like this:

```js
{
  "id": 0, //this id is the last id on this list plus 1(so first is 0 next one 1 and so on..) 
  "address": "Calle pizzarro 56",
  "appliesOn": 1, // also default value so dont worry
  "areas": [
    {
      "id": 83,
      "areaLevelId": 1,
      "name": "Portugal",
      "areaPosition": null,
      "parentAreas": [],
      "childAreas": []
    },
    {
      "id": 340,
      "areaLevelId": 3,
      "name": "Algarve",
      "areaPosition": null,
      "parentAreas": [],
      "childAreas": []
    },
    {
      "id": 340,
      "areaLevelId": 5,
      "name": "Albufeira",
      "areaPosition": null,
      "parentAreas": [],
      "childAreas": []
    },
    {
      "id": 12485,
      "areaLevelId": 7,
      "name": "hi how are you?",
      "areaPosition": {
        "latitude": 234,
        "longitude":79879
      },
      "parentAreas": [],
      "childAreas": []
    }
  ],
  "recordStatus": 1 //it handles by other way so for now 1 is ok
}
```

The problem is with areas, when name == 1 the value goes to `areaLevelId` = 1 and so on. When `areaLevelId`=7 theres a exception and takes the `latitude` and `longitude` and create an array with this.
What I did until now is this:

```js
function objectifyForm(fields) {

        var returnArray = {};

        returnArray["areas"] = [];

        jQuery.each(fields, function (i, field) {

            if (!isNaN(field.name) && field.value != "") {

                returnArray["areas"].push({
                    "id": (field.value.toLowerCase()),
                    "areaLevelId": (field.name)
                })

            } else if (field.name == "latitud" && field.name == "longitude") {
                //returnArray["areas"][3].push({
                //    returnArray["areas"]["areaPosition"] = [];
                //})
            } else {
                returnArray[field.name.toLowerCase()] = field.value + "";
            }
        });
        return returnArray;
    }
```

But this is wrong because Im not sure how to keep going.
Its first time I did something like;

> 1) take values from a form with `serializeArray()`
>
> 2) then create a function that places that info in a object with a concrete shape.
>
> 3) push that array to the global array

pd: parentAreas, childAreas always **empty** , and areaPosition has `latitude` and `longitude` when `areaLevelId == 7`
How I could achieve this??, thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```js
var arr = [
  { name: "Address", value: "Calle pizzarro 56" },
  { name: "1", value: "83" },
  { name: "3", value: "340" },
  { name: "5", value: "340" },
  { name: "7", value: "hi how are you?" },
  { name: "latitud", value: "87798" },
  { name: "longitude", value: "-8,208914" }
];

function objectifyForm(fields) {
  var address = fields.find(function(item) {
    return item.name === "Address";
  });
  var latitude = fields.find(function(item) {
    return item.name === "latitud";
  });
  var longitude = fields.find(function(item) {
    return item.name === "longitude";
  });
  var areas = fields.filter(function(item) {
    return (
      item.name !== "Address" &&
      item.name !== "latitud" &&
      item.name !== "longitude"
    );
  });

  var result = {
    id: 0,
    address: address.value,
    appliesOn: 1,
    recordStatus: 1
  };

  result.areas = areas.map(function(area) {
    return {
      id: area.value,
      areaLevelId: area.name,
      name: "Whatever",
      areaPosition:
        area.name === "7"
          ? { latitude: latitude.value, logitude: longitude.value }
          : null,
      parentAreas: [],
      childAreas: []
    };
  });

  return result;
}

var result = objectifyForm(arr);

console.log(result);
```

I simplified the `objectifyForm` function a little by extracting the relevant information before filling out the `areas` array, so it's easier to work with.

Also, I am not sure where you're getting `areas[index].name` from, but I'll leave that up to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That whats exaclty what I need!!, thank you very much Ill read with calm to understand why and apply to another forms.The `areas[index].name` is automatic if its has its `AreaLevel` and the right `id`. So thank you so much!!